# state pressed imageview with picasso library not working

Tags: android, xml, picasso

i get a problem using android:state_pressed with picasso

this is my code on my Activity  : 
thanks to Mahmoud Elmorabea
 **UPDATE my final code is **

```
final StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    final Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(this.getApplicationContext());
target_selected = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Drawable drawImage2 = new BitmapDrawable(
                    getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap);
            stateListDrawable
                    .addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                            drawImage2);
            stateListDrawable.addState(
                    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_activated },
                    drawImage2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };
    picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.akadblack)
            .into(target_selected);
    target_normal = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Drawable drawImage = new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext()
                    .getResources(), bitmap);
            stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, drawImage);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };

    picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.akad)
            .into(target_normal);

    imgAkad.setImageDrawable(stateListDrawable);
```

here on btnStart XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/resepsi" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/resepsiblack" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/resepsi" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

and last on my layout xml i put an imageview like this :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStart"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/start" />
```

i've tried some answer from here but still not working, even the imageview not rendering.

can anyone give me some example how to use picasso with selector state for imageview ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load both images that want to use as selectors synchronously.

Then use the following to set the selectors dynamically:

```
Bitmap bmpPressed = Picasso.with(context).get(url);
Bitmap bmpNotPressed = Picasso.with(context).get(url);
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    bmpPressed);
states.addState(new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    bmpNotPressed);
```

i don''t know if method get() exists in Picasso, i have done this before with [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: i've update my questions too, i create like what you do but the state still not working...

Comment: don't tell picasso to do anything to your imageview, you should setImageDrawable once to your imageview with setImageDrawable(stateListDrawable), lose the load().into() lines, they might be overriding what you're doing, plus you should set the stateListDrawable in the callback, not right after you start loading the images

Comment: it solved, i just change my state_selected to state_pressed, thanks anyway Mahmoud! :)